# Adobe Air SQLite performance vs SQLite cli

Tags: performance, sqlite, air

I have simple SQL table structure where there is three tables: **entry** (~70k rows), **tag** (~27k rows) and **entry_tag** (~2.5M rows). **entry_tag** -table contains relations between entries and tags (n-n relation) like this **entry_tag** (*entry_id*, *tag_id*, *...*).

When I first tried to fetch all the *entry_id*s with particular tag, I made query like

```
SELECT entry_id FROM entry_tag et, tag t 
WHERE t.id=et.tag_id AND t.name LIKE 'Something';
```

For no apparent reason query took over 6 secs on Adobe Air app on Win7 x64 (i5-2500K, 8GB RAM, 7200rpm hdd), which is way too slow (particularly with more complex `INTERSECT` queries). In SQLite command line tool query returned results immediately. I compared `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` between cli and Air (using Air based SQLite Sorcerer) and the results where identical. Both queries were using indices.

After I restructured the query by switching the order of the tables, performance got multiplied in Air to 250ms, which is satisfactory:

```
SELECT entry_id FROM tag t, entry_tag et
WHERE et.tag_id=t.id AND t.name LIKE 'Something';
```

So I was left wondering, why the cli tool was so much faster than Adobe Air environment? For background information I have generated the db file with PHP (all columns `INTEGER` or `TEXT`).

Here is the query plan for the original slow query:

```
sele  order          from  deta
----  -------------  ----  ----
0     0              0     SCAN TABLE entry_tag AS et USING INDEX idx_et_eid (~1000000 rows)
0     1              1     SEARCH TABLE tag AS t USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
```

(~1000000 rows looks anyways bad ;)

Comment: Have you tried to use ANALYZE command prior to query? Maybe the query analyzer would choose some other way then. Also you would get more accurate number of rows which are scanned.

Comment: Thanks. ANALYZE helped. Complicated queries are now much faster. If I understood documentation right, ANALYZE should be executed again after significant changes to database. Anyways, performance gap between Air and cli with the same database is quite peculiar.

Comment: Yes, this command is not run automatically, so you'll have to run it by hand as you mention.